# Подключение стилей и скриптов из vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть готовые скрипты и стили для странички.
Стили - это переписанный под собственные нужды бутстрап.
Скрипты - самописные.
Как сделать, чтобы рельсы брали изображения из `app/assets/images` , а стили и скрипты из `app/vendor/assets/stylesheets` и `app/vendor/assets/javascripts`?
Пробовал, по одному из ответов,добавлять в `aplication.rb` строку `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "javascripts")`, но ничего не изменялось.

Для стилей использовал временный костыль, который мне не очень нравится, записав содержимое двух файлов в файл `app/vendor/assets/stylesheets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если скрипты и стили по сути не являются сторонними ("переписанный под собственные нужды бутстрап" уже тоже нельзя назвать сторонним), то почему вы хотите положить их в vendor? Там имеет смысл хранить third-party ресурсы, которые вы никак не меняете и по необходимости обновляете, скопировав вручную новую версии.

Вообще достаточно включить эти файлы в манифесты application.js и application.css, чтобы assets pipeline их подхватил. В assets.path они попадают по умолчанию.

UPDATE: Очень коротко о том, как работает assets pipeline.

У вас есть js и css файлы в папках app/assets, lib/assets и vendor/assets. В app/assets лежат манифесты (в самом простом случае их будет всего два - application.js и application.css), в которых вы перечисляете все нужные вам ассеты.

Можно указать `require_tree .`, тогда будут автоматически включены все файлы из app/assets. Можно написать `require filename`, искать файл с таким именем приложение будет в app/, lib/ и vendor/ - в assets/(javascripts или stylesheets). Мне больше нравится второй вариант, позволяет контролировать порядок файлов, в первом случае они перечисляются по алфавиту.

В лэйауте приложения (views/layouts/application.html.erb) в head вы указываете два тега

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

По сути, это ваши манифесты, которые и говорят, какой css/js загрузить. В продакшне все файлы из манифеста будут скомпилированы, минифицированы, получат fingerprint для кэширования.

Я думаю, вам стоит создать новый отдельный вопрос с вашей ошибкой в js. Пожалуйста, приложите к нему сразу код application.js и оригинальный текст ошибки.

Comment: а как их включить через манифесты? Я много документаций читал, но никак не понял про `require ...`

Comment: Решил вопрос. Подключением всех файлов через ‘app/asset/*’. Но теперь проблема в том. Что js вроде подключён к проекту. Но он не работает. В консоли пишется что, «что то используется как функция, хотя ей не является». В ответах так же нашёл предположение что скрипт 2 разв запускается. Посмотрев у себя, ничего криминального не обнаружил.

Comment: @QWD666, обновила ответ

Comment: Спасибо, вчера опытным путем все это повторил. Понял почему сходу у меня все это не работало.Надо было просто перезапустить сервер. По поводу ошибки все оказалось просто, надо было всего лишь обновть jquery с 1.х на 3.х
Спасибо за объяснения. Стало понятнее.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)